# Missing Google Apps after 4.1.2 was built in Nexus S

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-nexus-s, google-apps

I built Android 4.1.2 from source for my Nexus S using [these instructions](http://source.android.com/source/). Later I found that there are no Google Apps on the phone and so I cannot set up my Google account or use the Play Store or Google Maps. I tried to download the Google Apps from [here](http://www.teamandroid.com/gapps/) and installed them from the SD card but nothing happened. How can I get them installed?

Also, is there any other way I can install Google Apps?

Comment: How exactly did you install the gapps package from your SD card? Did literally *nothing* happen, or did it claim to succeed or something else entirely?

Comment: No while installing it did not give me any error. It said installed, I did it from the recovery. But when I reboot the phone, I do not see any Gapps in my phone.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to download the Gapps from here and installed them from the SD
>   card but nothing happened. How can I get them installed?

perhaps there is not enough memory in system. Check and flash a lighter version with only essential apps(or trim down the package on your own)

Comment: It should not be the case since I flashed everything and tried to install it again

Comment: When you do not have enough space in system partition, it does happen.

Comment: I understand.. But in my case it has huge memory available

Comment: check out this [link](http://goo.im/gapps) and try one of these.

Answer (score 0):

in windows, install/use Nexus Root Toolkit to install the playstore .apk, then re-install missing gapps direct from playstore.